# How to getting an empty array when parsing XML?

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I was tasked with writing a Go utility that takes an XML file, parses it, and returns it in **JSON**.

Here is an example of the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tracks clid="020">
  <track uuid="551" category="s" route="8" vehicle_type="trolleybus" >
    <point
      latitude="53.61491"
      longitude="55.90922"
      avg_speed="24"
      direction="270"
      time="13122022:072116"
    />
  </track>
  <track uuid="552" category="s" route="6" vehicle_type="trolleybus">
    <point
      latitude="53.68321"
      longitude="57.90922"
      avg_speed="42"
      direction="181"
      time="13122022:072216"
    />
  </track>
</tracks>
```

I wrote the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Tracks struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"tracks" json:"-"`
    Clid    string   `xml:"clid,attr" json:"clid"`
    Tracks  []Track  `xml:"track" json:"track_list"`
}

type Track struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"tracks"`
    Uuid        string   `xml:"uuid,attr" json:"uuid"`
    Category    string   `xml:"category,attr" json:"category"`
    Route       string   `xml:"route,attr" json:"route"`
    VehicleType string   `xml:"vehicle_type,attr" json:"vehicle_type"`
    Point       Point    `xml:"point" json:"point"`
}

type Point struct {
    Latitude  string `xml:"latitude,attr" json:"latitude"`
    Longitude string `xml:"longitude,attr" json:"longitude"`
    AvgSpeed  string `xml:"avg_speed,attr" json:"avg_speed"`
    Direction string `xml:"direction,attr" json:"direction"`
    Time      string `xml:"time,attr" json:"time"`
}

func main() {
    rawXmlData := `
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <tracks clid="020">
            <track uuid="551" category="s" route="8" vehicle_type="trolleybus">
                <point latitude="53.61491" longitude="55.90922" avg_speed="24" direction="270" time="13122022:072116"/>
            </track>
            <track uuid="552" category="s" route="6" vehicle_type="trolleybus">
                <point latitude="53.68321" longitude="57.90922" avg_speed="42" direction="181" time="13122022:072216"/>
            </track>
        </tracks>
    `

    var tracks Tracks

    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(rawXmlData), &tracks)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(tracks)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf(string(jsonData))
}
```

[Go.dev](https://go.dev/play/p/qfYQF-9Ns_p)

But, unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get the following in the console:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 expected element type <tracks> but have <track>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For starters, that's not valid XML data. That leading `compressed=0&data=` isn't XML. Secondly, you're not checking the return value from `xml.Unmarshal`, which may contain clues to the problem.

Comment: @larsks, thank you for your reply. This data comes from the server.

Comment: @larsks, if you remove `compressed=0&data=` and print the error, it outputs the following to the console: `{"clid":"020","track_list":[]} panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x10c0958]`

Comment: The sample code you've posted here contains invalid XML data. Until you deal with that problem, there's not much point in us examining your code in further detail, because that data will *never* work. You need to figure that part out *first*, and update the code in your question. Next, you need to check the error returned by `xml.Unmarshal`, print it out and see if that suggests a path to the solution (and update your code to show how you're checking and responding to the error).

Comment: Note that there are *additional* problems with the XML data in your question: even after you remove the invalid leader, it's still not syntactically valid. If this is actually what you're receiving from the server, then there's a bug on the server side. You can paste it into something like https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator for details.

Comment: I see your edit, but you're still not checking the error returned by `xml.Unmarshal`; you're only checking the result of `json.Marshal`. Also, re: "P.S. I had never programmed in Go before today.", note that most of your problems here are not Go problems (there may be one here, but there's a bunch of stuff to resolve first). On second thought, maybe error checking is a bit of a Go issue: you *always* need to check error returns in Go, because that's how problems are communicated to the caller.

Comment: @larsks, sorry, you were right, I had invalid XML. I made a mistake when writing the code. I fixed the XML and handled the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would move the discussion to an answer, since I think you're pretty close. As I mentioned, you need to check the error returned by `xml.Unmarshal`. That might look like this:

```
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(rawXmlData), &tracks); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Now that you have valid XML data in your code, we can produce meaningful errors; with the above error check in place, running your code produces:

```
panic: expected element type <tracks> but have <track>

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /home/lars/tmp/go/main.go:48 +0x12f
```

That's happening because of a minor typo in your data structures; in the definition of your `Track` struct, you have:

```
type Track struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"tracks"`
    Uuid        string   `xml:"uuid,attr" json:"uuid"`
    Category    string   `xml:"category,attr" json:"category"`
    Route       string   `xml:"route,attr" json:"route"`
    VehicleType string   `xml:"vehicle_type,attr" json:"vehicle_type"`
    Point       Point    `xml:"point" json:"point"`
}
```

You've mis-tagged the `XMLName` attribute as `tracks` when it should be `track`:

```
type Track struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"track"`
    Uuid        string   `xml:"uuid,attr" json:"uuid"`
    Category    string   `xml:"category,attr" json:"category"`
    Route       string   `xml:"route,attr" json:"route"`
    VehicleType string   `xml:"vehicle_type,attr" json:"vehicle_type"`
    Point       Point    `xml:"point" json:"point"`
}
```

Lastly -- and this isn't directly related to the problem -- you should avoid naming a variable `error`, because that's the name of the built-in data type of errors. I would modify your call to `json.Marshal` like this:

```
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(tracks)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

You don't need to `panic()` on errors; this is just a convenient way to bail out of the code.

---

With these changes in place, if we compile and run the code we get as output (formatted with `jq`):

```
{
  "clid": "020",
  "track_list": [
    {
      "XMLName": {
        "Space": "",
        "Local": "track"
      },
      "uuid": "551",
      "category": "s",
      "route": "8",
      "vehicle_type": "trolleybus",
      "point": {
        "latitude": "53.61491",
        "longitude": "55.90922",
        "avg_speed": "24",
        "direction": "270",
        "time": "13122022:072116"
      }
    },
    {
      "XMLName": {
        "Space": "",
        "Local": "track"
      },
      "uuid": "552",
      "category": "s",
      "route": "6",
      "vehicle_type": "trolleybus",
      "point": {
        "latitude": "53.68321",
        "longitude": "57.90922",
        "avg_speed": "42",
        "direction": "181",
        "time": "13122022:072216"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Note that you don't even need that `XMLName` element in your structure; if we remove it completely so that we have:

```
type Track struct {
    Uuid        string `xml:"uuid,attr" json:"uuid"`
    Category    string `xml:"category,attr" json:"category"`
    Route       string `xml:"route,attr" json:"route"`
    VehicleType string `xml:"vehicle_type,attr" json:"vehicle_type"`
    Point       Point  `xml:"point" json:"point"`
}
```

Then we get as output (formatted with `jq`):

```
{
  "clid": "020",
  "track_list": [
    {
      "uuid": "551",
      "category": "s",
      "route": "8",
      "vehicle_type": "trolleybus",
      "point": {
        "latitude": "53.61491",
        "longitude": "55.90922",
        "avg_speed": "24",
        "direction": "270",
        "time": "13122022:072116"
      }
    },
    {
      "uuid": "552",
      "category": "s",
      "route": "6",
      "vehicle_type": "trolleybus",
      "point": {
        "latitude": "53.68321",
        "longitude": "57.90922",
        "avg_speed": "42",
        "direction": "181",
        "time": "13122022:072216"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and response! Good luck and success to you!

Answer (score 1):

```
type Track struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"tracks"`
```

should be "track" not "tracks"

https://go.dev/play/p/kg-Dyep8Fv9

Comment: In fact, that `XMLName` field isn't even necessary.